# Does Entity Framework Core support MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb, entity-framework-core

Does Entity Framework Core support MariaDB?

I see it's not among the list of [supported providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/ef/core/providers/), but MySQL is. Maybe the MySQL provider would work against MariaDB?

Comment: Did you look to : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/ ?

Comment: @OrcusZ of course I did, that link is part of my question.

Comment: So go for pomelo as @mode777 say's or use the MySQL provider from MS.

Answer (score 11):

I'm using the Pomelo MySql provider with Maria DB. It works great. MariaDB is just a fork of MySql,

Comment: Be careful: not everything that supports MySQL supports MariaDB. I encountered an example a few months ago; sadly I don't remember its name.

Comment: I have a problem with MariaDB related to the generated sql for row version, it works fine with mysql but not with MariaDB

Comment: I also have bad experience with MariaDB, same code works just fine in MySql but not in MariaDB